# Operator '*=' cannot be applied to types 'number | bigint' and 'number'.",

Tags: typescript, types

I have this permutation function from [js-combinatorics](https://github.com/dankogai/js-combinatorics/blob/master/combinatorics.js) which i want to configure

```
const _BI = typeof BigInt == 'function' ? BigInt : Number;

const _crop = (n) => n <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER ? Number(n) : _BI(n);

function permutation(n, k) {
  if (n < 0)
      throw new RangeError(`negative n is not acceptable`);
  if (k < 0)
      throw new RangeError(`negative k is not acceptable`);
  if (0 == k)
      return 1;
  if (n < k)
      return 0;
  [n, k] = [_BI(n), _BI(k)];
  let p = _BI(1);
  while (k--) 
      p *= n--;
  return _crop(p);

}
```

ts gives me in  `p *= n--;`

`Operator '*=' cannot be applied to types 'number | bigint' and 'number'.`

How can I fix the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a limitation of `|` operator and `*=` operator.

1. `*=` operator can't operates with mixed types. You must put in both sides the same type, or `number` or `bigint`
2. Althoug if you put a generic template `N extends number|bigint` for both `n` and `p` you have troubles too because `n` can be a `bigint` or a `number` or a `bigint|number` (some kind of simultaneous typing). See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39569